# Change my ubuntu 12.04 to 13.04

Tags: upgrade

currently i am runing ubuntu 12.04.I Installed ubntu 13.04 on a USB with UNetbootin and now i want to change my ubuntu 12.04 to ubuntu 13.04.how can i format root partition and install ubuntu 13.04 ? I dont want to lose my /home data
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 then to Ubuntu 13.04. You can only skip releases if you are upgrading from an LTS release to another LTS.

What I recommend is that you create a new partition and install 13.04 as a "dual boot."

To upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10, I would recommend that you boot from the Ubuntu 12.10 DVD or USB boot drive, and choose the option to Upgrade.

[image]

Comment: From the command line `sudo do-release-upgrade` would get you from 12.04 to 12.10. That's an LTS or Long Term Support version. You could stop there and many people do stay with LTS. Issuing the command a second time would move you to 13.04.** Of course, you should backup everything before you make any major changes.**